# Javascript - Get all unique permutations of a string (special case)

Tags: javascript, string, permutation

Given a string like "this is a search with spaces", I want to return all permutations of that string where the spaces are replaced with a dash. For example, this is the result that I want:

["this-is-a-search-with-spaces"] 
["this-is-a-search-with", "spaces"] 
["this", "is-a-search-with-spaces"] 
["this-is", "a-search-with-spaces"] 
["this-is-a-search", "with-spaces"] 
["this-is-a", "search-with-spaces"] 
...and so on.

I can do half of this, but the problem is that it matches ["query1-query2", "query3"] but not the opposite way around like ["query1", "query2-query3"].

This is my current code:

```js
const sliced = query.split(/ +/g)
let permutations = []
for (let i = 1; i <= sliced.length; i++) {
  let permuteArr = []
  for (let j = 0; j < sliced.length; j+=i) {
    permuteArr.push(sliced.slice(j, j+i).join("-"))
  }
  permutations.push(permuteArr)
}
```

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a recursive generator that yields the combinations:

```js
function permutations(query) {
    
    function* iterRecur(sliced) {
        if (sliced.length == 1) return yield sliced;
        for (const result of iterRecur(sliced.slice(1))) {
            yield [sliced[0] + "-" + result[0], ...result.slice(1)];
            yield [sliced[0], ...result];
        }
    }

    const sliced = query.split(/ +/g);
    return [...iterRecur(sliced)];
}

console.log(permutations("this is a test"));
```

Comment: Your solution is wonderful, thank you very much!